# Comparing values of a multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

```
$data = [];
$data['set1'] = ['label1'=>'001', 'label2'=>'002'];
$data['set2'] = ['label1'=>'003', 'label2'=>'004'];
$data['set3'] = ['label1'=>'001', 'label2'=>'006'];
$data['set4'] = ['label1'=>'001', 'label2'=>'002'];
```

I'd like to check if value of `labelx` in any `setx` is identical. All I can think of is run `foreach` loops to compare one set with the rest, one at a time.

Is there any elegant solution that checks for similar values in ALL sets without doing the loops manually?

Comment: Why doesn't it seem right? You could maybe use a function like `array_search` or `array_find`, I keep forgetting), but for a specific case like this you may still need a loop anyway.

Comment: Not clear, `labelx`?? Do you want to check each label1 to each lebel2???

Comment: Having asked 587 questions, still didn't know how to ask a clear question?

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and [array_count_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) will do the trick.

First get the column values as array using **array_column** and then find identical values in an array using **array_count_values**.

Like this:

```
<?php

$data = [];
$data['set1'] = ['label1'=>'001', 'label2'=>'002'];
$data['set2'] = ['label1'=>'003', 'label2'=>'004'];
$data['set3'] = ['label1'=>'001', 'label2'=>'006'];
$data['set4'] = ['label1'=>'001', 'label2'=>'002'];

$label1_values=array_column($data,'label1');
$label2_values=array_column($data,'label2');

print_r(array_count_values($label1_values));
print_r(array_count_values($label2_values));

?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [001] => 3
    [003] => 1
)
Array
(
    [002] => 2
    [004] => 1
    [006] => 1
)
```